# Beautifulsoup4 and Python 2.7.6

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a script that works without major flaws with Python 2.7.3 and 2.7.5+, but fails to work with 2.7.6. I suspect that it can be related to how Beautifulsoup handles unicode, but I am not sure.

It basically does something like:

```
# harvest HTML, store it in the variable html
html = harvest()
# the HTML is a string of ascii characters (no extended anything)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
trs = soup.find_all('tr',event_attr_id=True)

for tr in trs:
    # do stuff
    # this never executes with python 2.7.6 (it doesn't get it)
```

When `pprint(soup.prettify())`, I see that bs has included multiple `\xa0` characters. I don't care what bs does with my `soup`, but the thing is that it isn't working with Python 2.7.6.

Would you give me some leads to a possible fix? Is it encoding related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem (that it was not easy to infer just by the question) was related to the parser that BeautifulSoup was using, and the fact that the parser didn't like the html that was receiving (because it wasn't a whole page but the contents of a div from an ajax response). I think it was using `html5lib`.

I came up with 2 working solutions:

Fixing it for the built-in parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join('<html><body><table>',html,'</table></body></html>'))
```

Using a different parser:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
```

The fact that html5lib isn't lenient enough to accept the stuff I am feeding may be installation-specific (i.e. older version of the html5lib).